# php associative array, preg_match and loop

Tags: php, arrays, associative

I have an associative array from which I extract two numbers with regular expression

```
<?php           
 $link = array (
 "model_one" => "Only 50.95 usd for 2 years or 700.30 usd.",
 "model_two" => "Only 70.95 usd for 2 years or 900.20 usd.");
 foreach ($link as $key=>$links) {
    $pattern = '/.\d+(?:\.\d{2})?((?<=[0-9])(?= usd))/';
    preg_match_all($pattern,$links,$result);
    $final = array();
    foreach($result[0] as $k=>$v) {
    $final[]=$v;
    echo $final[0]; // print 50.95 50.95 70.95 70.95    
    }
 }
?>
```

I was not able to retrieve every single number associated to  key

Example:

```
model_one 50.95
model_one 700.30
model_two 70.95
model_two 900.20
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to loop through the array containing matched values:

```
foreach ($link as $key => $links) {
    $pattern = '/\d+(?:\.\d{2})?((?<=[0-9])(?= usd))/';
    preg_match_all($pattern,$links,$result);

    foreach ($result[0] as $amt) {
        echo "$key $amt\n";
    }
}
```

Note that I've also removed the period character (`.`) from the beginning of your regular expression. It will match any character that's not a space. This will cause the capture to contain a space at the beginning.

Output:

```
model_one 50.95
model_one 700.30
model_two 70.95
model_two 900.20
```

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/124298)

Comment: thank you so much Miley,
for your reply.
In this way i have model_ associated to two number:
model_one 50.95 and 700.30.
how to pick a single number separately  to put into the DB:

INSERT INTO ... (col1, col2) VALUES (50.95, 700.30)
Thanks again

Comment: @user3332537: Then you don't need a loop. Simply use `implode()`. Demo: https://eval.in/124440

Comment: @ Amal Murali Ok, very well.
Another question if I use query to update single value:
UPDATE model_ one SET first_price = 50.95 and SET second_price =  700.30
how can I do it

Comment: @user3332537: The values are stored in `$result` array. You just need to access it. See demo: https://eval.in/124473 (If you have any more questions, please ask it as a [new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask))

Comment: I appreciate your answers